# Clean-up mounted()-attached script in destroyed() callback in Vue component

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, script-tag

I am programmatically adding necessary scripts into some of my Vue components, like so:

```
mounted() {
    const
        googleRecaptchaScript = document.createElement('script'),
        recaptchaURL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
    googleRecaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', recaptchaURL);
    googleRecaptchaScript.setAttribute('id', 'grecaptchascript');
    document.head.appendChild(googleRecaptchaScript);
},
```

Now, I noticed that if I navigate away from the component and back into it, without refreshing the page wholesale, that Vue will start loading in duplicate copies of the things I attach in that `mounted()` call. So I wanted to clean them up as follows:

```
beforeDestroy() {
    const gsc = document.getElementById('grecaptchascript');
    gsc.parentElement.removeChild(gsc);
},
```

However it seems like the `id` of that script is never even set, so the cleanup step fails silently.

Am I doing it totally wrong? Is a better pattern for doing this? If not, why isn't my `<script>` getting the `id` I'm setting?

Footnote: I am aware that using an `id` is problematic here since we're talking about duplicated elements. I'll change this later. Please consider the general case of selecting by any arbitrary attribute, if that helps. I've tried other attributes but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that such cleaning is not necessary: after loading the script all definitions of functions and variables fall into the global scope, and after unloading the script they are not deleted.

What you need is to check that the scripts are already loaded, and do not load more than once:

```
mounted() {
  const gsc = document.getElementById('grecaptchascript');
  if (!gsc) {
    const
      googleRecaptchaScript = document.createElement('script'),
      recaptchaURL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
    googleRecaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', recaptchaURL);
    googleRecaptchaScript.setAttribute('id', 'grecaptchascript');
    document.head.appendChild(googleRecaptchaScript);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see why your solution is better in this case. It bothers me that we can't easily clean up the script-caused definitions, surely it's cluttering the namespace and the memory footprint of the page.

Comment: @machineyearning Another option is to download scripts in iframe, which you can really remove.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was exactly, but for future reference this solution worked and seemed fairly good for my case because it selects on the prefix of the `script`'s `src` attribute:

```
mounted() {
    const
        googleRecaptchaScript = document.createElement('script'),
        recaptchaURL = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=${this.$i18n.locale}`;
    googleRecaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', recaptchaURL);
    document.head.appendChild(googleRecaptchaScript);
},
beforeDestroy() {
    const recaptchaScripts = document.querySelectorAll('script[src^="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"]');
    for (let i = 0; i < recaptchaScripts.length; i += 1) {
        recaptchaScripts[i].parentElement.removeChild(recaptchaScripts[i]);
    }
},
```

I'm pretty sure `id` would have worked fine too, I was just being dumb. And I'd still be interested if anyone has a better solution, because "manually" (programmatically) selecting and removing elements from the page seems kinda dirty.